# How does spring oauth2sso works? Why this redirect sequence happen?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I want to write hello world example to understand SSO/oauth2

I took following example:

http://www.baeldung.com/sso-spring-security-oauth2

First of all I need to say that it works properply. My question is wy it is working.

My question related with client application. It is simple application which contains only several classes. The most important class is:

**UiSecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class UiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/", "/login**")
          .permitAll()
          .anyRequest()
          .authenticated();
    }
}
```

**UiWebConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class UiWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(final DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
        registry.addViewController("/")
            .setViewName("forward:/index");
        registry.addViewController("/index");
        registry.addViewController("/securedPage");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

}
```

and following configuration:

```
server:
    port: 8082
    context-path: /ui
    session:
      cookie:
        name: UISESSION
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: SampleClientId
      clientSecret: secret
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/authorize
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8081/auth/user/me
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
```

**Questions:**
1.When I start application and follows the link http://localhost:8082/ui/ I see login page.

this page contains follwong `href`:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="securedPage">Login</a>
```

When I click on this `href` some sort of magic happens and in the network tab I see:
[image]
As you can see
1. `http://localhost:8082/ui/securedPage` redirects to `http://localhost:8082/ui/login`
2. `http://localhost:8082/ui/login` redirects to `http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/authorize?client_id=SampleClientId&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8082/ui/login&response_type=code&state=DuO4CX` (!!!another domain!!!how?)
3. `http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/authorize?client_id=SampleClientId&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8082/ui/login&response_type=code&state=DuO4CX` redirects to `http://localhost:8081/auth/login` and I see login form where I can input credentials

I don't understand why this works at this way.
**1.** Why  `http://localhost:8082/ui/securedPage` redirects to `http://localhost:8082/ui/login` ???
I don't have mapping for this url. When I start application I see follwing mapping log:

```
2018-04-12 19:50:04.069  INFO 4388 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Root mapping to handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2018-04-12 19:50:04.069  INFO 4388 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/index] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2018-04-12 19:50:04.069  INFO 4388 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/securedPage] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2018-04-12 19:50:04.085  INFO 4388 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-04-12 19:50:04.088  INFO 4388 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler]
```

all subesequent steps is unclear too.  Please explain it in details.

Answer (score 3):

`http://localhost:8082/ui/login` is not shown in a list of mapped URLs because it is handled by `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` which initiates the authentication flow.

I think the best way to explain all the steps is to use [OAuth 2.0 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1).

Here is the flow scheme:

```
 +----------+
 | Resource |
 |   Owner  |
 |          |
 +----------+
      ^
      |
     (B)
 +----|-----+          Client Identifier      +---------------+
 |         -+----(A)-- & Redirection URI ---->|               |
 |  User-   |                                 | Authorization |
 |  Agent  -+----(B)-- User authenticates --->|     Server    |
 |          |                                 |               |
 |         -+----(C)-- Authorization Code ---<|               |
 +-|----|---+                                 +---------------+
   |    |                                         ^      v
  (A)  (C)                                        |      |
   |    |                                         |      |
   ^    v                                         |      |
 +---------+                                      |      |
 |         |>---(D)-- Authorization Code ---------'      |
 |  Client |          & Redirection URI                  |
 |         |                                             |
 |         |<---(E)----- Access Token -------------------'
 +---------+       (w/ Optional Refresh Token)
```

*Resource Owner* - It's a user
*User-Agent* - User's browser
*Client* - [Web application deployed on 8082 port](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-sso/spring-security-sso-ui)
*Authorization Server* - [Web application deployed on 8081 port](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-sso/spring-security-sso-auth-server)

> **(A)**  The client initiates the flow by directing the resource owner's
> user-agent to the authorization endpoint.  The client includes
> its client identifier, requested scope, local state, and a
> redirection URI to which the authorization server will send the
> user-agent back once access is granted (or denied).

In your case when a user tries to access `securedPage`, she is redirected to `http://localhost:8082/ui/login` which starts the authentication flow.
After that the user is redirected to the authorization endpoint. In your case it's `http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/authorize`.

> **(B)**  The authorization server authenticates the resource owner (via
> the user-agent) and establishes whether the resource owner
> grants or denies the client's access request.

Here the user is redirected to the authorization server login page (`http://localhost:8081/auth/login`).

> **(C)**  Assuming the resource owner grants access, the authorization
> server redirects the user-agent back to the client using the
> redirection URI provided earlier (in the request or during
> client registration).  The redirection URI includes an
> authorization code and any local state provided by the client
> earlier.

If the authentication was successful, the user is redirected back to the client using the url provided on step (A) in the request to the authorization endpoint. In your case it was `&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8082/ui/login`. Redirection includes the authorization code generated by the authorization server.

> **(D)**  The client requests an access token from the authorization
> server's token endpoint by including the authorization code
> received in the previous step.  When making the request, the
> client authenticates with the authorization server.  The client
> includes the redirection URI used to obtain the authorization
> code for verification.

> **(E)**  The authorization server authenticates the client, validates the
> authorization code, and ensures that the redirection URI
> received matches the URI used to redirect the client in
> step (C).  If valid, the authorization server responds back with
> an access token and, optionally, a refresh token.

The client uses the authorization code to get an access token from the token endpoint (`http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/token`). The access token is used to access protected resources. In your case it's `http://localhost:8081/auth/user/me` which is used to fetch information about the user. This information is used to populate the security context.

Comment: Does **/login** just a reserved url where spring redirect you in case if you don't have authorization?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes, but you can change it using `security.oauth2.sso.login-path` property: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.12.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-single-sign-on

Comment: ok thanks. it't clear  Next step is credential unput and click submit. Server execute /login POST and returns following: http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/04/13/0005/3037/338909/09/88d2f63a03.jpg

Comment: then **http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/authorize?client_id=SampleClientId&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8082/ui/login&response_type=code&state=Rjb7k9** redirects to *http://localhost:8082/ui/login?code=pqJ8Wy&state=Rjb7k9**

Comment: then *http://localhost:8082/ui/login?code=pqJ8Wy&state=Rjb7k9* redirects to the *http://localhost:8082/ui/securedPage*

Comment: And I see this page.

Comment: Why I see this page now? I don't see anything new in cookies

Comment: UISESSION stores the ID of your HTTP session in the client application. When the flow finishes the security context is populated with the information about the current user. After that the security context is stored in the HTTP session. On each next request the information about the current user is taken from the HTTP session by it's ID provided in the UISESSION cookie.

Comment: How can I mofidy this code to add logout feature?Somehow to remove UISESSION from session?

Comment: Follow the guide: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_logout